# Count function calls with closure with function attribute

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to count how many times a function was called by adding an attribute to it. The counter works fine, but I'm not able to access its value from outside the function- see below. Why wouldn't `g.n` return `2` in my case?

```js
var countFunc = function (func) {
  func.n = 0

  return function () {
    func.n++;
    console.log('called ' + func.n + ' times')
    return func.apply(null, arguments)
  }
}

var f = function (x) { return x };
var g = countFunc(f)

console.log(g(1));  //called 1 times, 1
console.log(g(2)); //called 2 times, 2
console.log(g.n); //undefined
```

Comment: You are setting counter to original function use  `f.n`

Comment: Ok, I see. How should I do in order to transfer that property to the augmented function?

Comment: Check my answer.

Comment: Why the downvote? I clearly stated the issue and included a MCVE... Genuinely trying to understand what was wrong with my question in order to do better next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just save counter to the newly created function instead of the original one.

```js
var countFunc = function (func) {
  function wrapped () {
    wrapped.n++;
    console.log('called ' + wrapped.n + ' times')
    return func.apply(null, arguments)
  };
  
  wrapped.n = 0;
  
  return wrapped;
}

var f = function (x) { return x };
var g = countFunc(f)

console.log(g(1));  //called 1 times, 1
console.log(g(2)); //called 2 times, 2
console.log(g.n); //2
```